# ¿Cómo consultar cumpleaños a partir de hoy?

Tags: sql

Antes de eso estoy utilizando demo.db del software "Sybase Central " así que espero que entiendan.

Intento consultar a las personas que aún no cumplen en ese año. Puse ese código pero creo que no sea ese adecuado para consultar tal vez es otro código. Ademas me doy cuenta que es por los días por ejemplo si es el día 23 me muestra a partir del 23 .

```
 SELECT  e.givenname +' '+ e.surname 'Empleados', e.birthdate
 FROM employees e
 where (month(e.BirthDate) >= month(today())) and 
 (day(e.BirthDate) >= day(today()))
 order by month(birthdate) asc
```

Aquí la imagen me muestra la lista y es o fue 2 de febrero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podrías lograrlo haciendo un `SELECT` en base al mes-día mediante `DATE_FORMAT`

```
 SELECT  
     e.givenname +' '+ e.surname 'Empleados', 
     e.birthdate
 FROM employees e
 WHERE 
     DATE_FORMAT(e.BirthDate, 'mmdd') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), 'mmdd')
 ORDER BY 
     MONTH(e.BirthDate), DAY(e.BirthDate);
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> He usado intuitivamente el formato `mmdd` para obtener mes y día, pero
>   no uso SyBase para probarlo, si es otro formato el que debe usarse
>   sólo tienes que cambiarlo.